# Rubber: How to upload just some html.erb files into a running instance on Amazon aws ec2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rubber

Finally I managed to deploy the application in Amazon ec2, it's running ok, but now I just need to upload some new html.erb files, how I can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cap deploy:upload FILES=foo1.html.erb,foo2.html.erb
```

Will do the trick, but it'll always create a copy from your current app inside release folder, so for each update all application will be cloned.

Theres a way to do it automatically to keep just the last 2 or 3 releases?

Comment: By default only three copies are kept!